# Access Phone Gallery in Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I am developing a Web Application using Aurelia framework. I am trying to access Phone Gallery. There is an option to upload image. When someone clicks on upload then I want to access directly Phone gallery to upload image. Is this possible in Web Application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `input type file` will open the phone gallery

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg">
```